# SQL Server 2016 Management Studio regex \0

Tags: sql-server, regex, ssms

Is there any way to do the following in SSMS2016?

It worked SSMS 2012 and earlier, but not any more in SSMS 2016, SQL Server. Actually regex \0 dose not work as previous version, I think.

Text:

```
select * from abc where a=1
```

Find:

```
where|from
```

Replace:

```
\n\0
```

Results:

```
select * 
from abc 
where a=1
```

Comment: Are you talking of a `\0` in the regex pattern or in the replacement string?

Comment: Does $0 work? I can't test as I'm on SSMS 2014 and \0 works.

Answer (score 0):

There are syntax differences between the regular expressions that can be used in Find what strings and those that are valid in Microsoft .NET Framework programming. For example, in Find and Replace, the braces notation {} is used for tagged expressions. So the expression "zo{1}" matches all occurrences of "zo" followed by the tag 1, as in "Alonzo1" and "Gonzo1". But within the .NET Framework, the notation {} is used for quantifiers. So the expression "zo{1}" matches all occurrences of "z" followed by exactly one "o", as in "zone" but not "zoo".

[MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174214.aspx)

Here is MSDN documentation regarding 
[Substitutions in Regular Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0.aspx)